# mb_convert_case undefined function (Symfony2 FOS/UserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, mamp, mbstring

On my Symfony2 application, I am receiving an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function FOS\UserBundle\Util\mb_convert_case() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Util/Canonicalizer.php on line 18

I am using PHP 5.3.6.

Here is my PHPInfo showing that mbstring is enabled:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCMDv.png

If mbstring is enabled then why is mb_convert_case not being found?

Comment: IMHO, it does not work with the cli.

Comment: Then how did the documentation & tutorials for FOSUserBundle get it to work?

Comment: Do you know how to set up fastcgi php instead cli?

Comment: No I don't. Can I just add a query instead of using CLI?

Answer (score 6):

I found this:

Under Windows you must uncomment the line with php_mbstring.dll in your php.ini

I don't know if you're running a windows box or not.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X & MAMP for the local server.