# FOSuserBundle and php 5.5

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, fosuserbundle

Ive searched the PHPuserBundle documentation and cannot find any reference to php version support issues.

Ive just upgraded my php version to 5.6 (using XAMPP) and I get the following error when sending to login_check.

`Attempted to call function "mb_convert_case" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle\Util`

Is it best to stick with 5.4 for now? I tried 5.5 and got the same error.  My only reason for wanting to upgrade was to stay up to date, so its not life or death but Im curious.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to uncomment/add this line in your php.ini:

> extension=php_mbstring.dll

Comment: Run `php app/check.php` in console to find any PHP configuration requirements issues. Maybe you have multiple PHP versions installed. Also don't forget to restart web server after php.ini updating.

Comment: thanks for that.. I was being stupid and using xampp to load php.ini for editing.  When I load the right one its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version ("friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev") of FOSUSerBundle works with PHP>=5.3.2.

You can check this in packagist.org - https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

If you are working under Windows then you must uncomment php_mbstring.dll in php.ini file. Check this answer - [mb_convert_case undefined function (Symfony2 FOS/UserBundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422048/mb-convert-case-undefined-function-symfony2-fos-userbundle)